# Algorithm for Fuzzy Matching Multiple Word Phrases in a Paragraph

Tags: database, string, algorithm, search, fuzzy-search

First, I'm not looking for the actual fuzzy matching algorithm. We're using both Dice's Coefficient and Levenshtein Distance. I'm looking for the cleverest way to utilize these algorithms.

**The Goal:**

I'm trying to detect the names of cities in paragraph of text, in the order they occur. We have a list of ~1 million location names. I want to search through a paragraph of text, and detect when one of these locations are present, then store that city. Location names can be a single or multiple words.

**Example Paragraph:**

> Hi Mom! Sam and I are thinking of road tripping through **Canada** in the
>   next month. We know we can already stay at John's house in **Quebec
>   City**. I know you have traveled a lot in **Canada**, so I wanted to get
>   your advice.
>
> Like I said, we'd start in Quebec city, then probably drive to
>   **Miramichi** before heading to **Halifax**. After 2 days we want to go to
>   **Cape Breton**. Finally, we want to check out **Advocate Harbor** to see
>   things like the **Bay of Fundy**, **Digby**, and the **Pier of St. Elizabeth**
>
> Talk to you soon!

**Expected Results**

- Canada
- Quebec City
- Canada
- Miramichi
- Halifax
- Cape Breton
- Advocate Harbor
- Bay of Fundy
- Digby
- Pier of St. Elizabeth

**The Problem**

My current roadblock is how to detect location names with multiple words. I know I can split the paragraph into words, then compare them against my list, like:

1. Fuzzy match the first word against my list of location names
2. If no match, fuzzy match (first word + second word) against my list of location names
3. If no match, fuzzy match (first + second + third word) against my list of location names
4. ...etc

This is my current approach, but it is incredibly slow and inefficient. Is there a clever way I can accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can the paragraph be treat like a single line of string, and use some kind of string matching algorithm? such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm  to match multiple pattern (locations in your case)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't do Fuzzy matching but worked perfectly. Submit this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know that it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some string matching algorithm works perfectly well for you,

Here is a list for them: [String Matching Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

In your case, I think you need multiple pattern string matching one, such as [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)

Comment: This works great! As a reference for others, I ended up using the Aho-Corasick implementation from this gem: https://github.com/ahnick/ahocorasick